# How to add the simplest In-App Purchase?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, in-app-purchase

There are a lot of questions and a lot of answers about In-App Purchase on the AppStore. But how to add the simplest In-App Purchase?

The code should be as short as possible. No one command more than it's really required.

Comment: What part of those "lot of answers" don't you understand?  Have you tried searching for tutorials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply follow http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/, it's a good start.